# Emacs equivalent to :set list in vim

Tags: whitespace, highlighting

I'm looking for a way to display hidden characters like newline and tab characters in emacs. I am NOT trying to convert the characters, just display them in the current buffer.

In vi(m), I can do this with the `:set list` command. Additionally, I can customize the appearance of the characters something like this:

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
```

This makes it easy to see tabs and where new lines start. I desperately need this feature in emacs as well, can someone provide it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `M-x whitespace-mode` to toggle display of space, line breaks, etc. You can set `whitespace-style` to control what gets displayed. (Try `M-x customize-variable whitespace-style` to see what options are available.)

You might also try: `M-x customize-group whitespace`, to see all the related options -- whether to turn on whitespace-mode globally, how to display each kind of whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 3):

@glucas gave the standard answer for this question: Vanilla Emacs provides `whitespace-mode` out of the box.

EmacsWiki page [ShowWhiteSpace](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace) describes some other approaches, one of which is library [`highlight-chars.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el).

You can use [`highlight-chars.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el) to easily highlight any sets of characters that you choose, including whitespace characters. There are commands and functions to use on hooks.

You can highlight whitespace and other easily confused characters: spaces, tabs, hard spaces, and hard hyphens, as well as trailing whitespace.